unsupported addressable value (argument="target", value=null, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.11.1)
I have this smart contract:
 // SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;
contract Transaction {
    event EtherTransferred(address from, address to, uint256 amount, string category);
    function transferEther(address payable  to, string memory category) external payable  {
        uint amount = msg.value;
        (bool success, ) = to.call{value: amount}("");
        require(success, "Ether transfer failed");
        emit EtherTransferred(msg.sender, to, amount, category);
    }
}

and I wrote this test js hardhat test:
const { expect } = require("chai");
const { ethers, JsonRpcProvider } = require("hardhat");

describe("Transaction", function () {
  let Transaction;
  let transaction;

  beforeEach(async function () {
    Transaction = await ethers.getContractFactory("Transaction");
    transaction = await Transaction.deploy();
    await transaction.waitForDeployment(); 
  });

  it("Should transfer ether correctly", async function () {
    const initialBalance = await ethers.provider.getBalance(transaction.address);
    const amountInEther = 1;
    const amount = ethers.utils.parseEther(amountInEther.toString()); 
  
    
    const toAddress = "0xAb8483F64d9C6d1EcF9b849Ae677dD3315835cb2"; 
  
    const category = "Test";
  
    await expect(transaction.transferEther(toAddress, category, { value: amount }))
      .to.emit(transaction, "EtherTransferred")
      .withArgs(await ethers.provider.getSigner().getAddress(), toAddress, amount, category);
  
    const finalBalance = await ethers.provider.getBalance(transaction.address);
    expect(finalBalance).to.equal(initialBalance.sub(amount));
  });
});

but when I run
npx hardhat test 

i get this error:
TypeError: unsupported addressable value (argument="target", value=null, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.11.1)
      at makeError (node_modules\ethers\src.ts\utils\errors.ts:687:21)
      at assert (node_modules\ethers\src.ts\utils\errors.ts:715:25)
      at assertArgument (node_modules\ethers\src.ts\utils\errors.ts:727:5)
      at resolveAddress (node_modules\ethers\src.ts\address\checks.ts:122:19)
      at HardhatEthersProvider._getAddress (node_modules\@nomicfoundation\hardhat-ethers\src\internal\hardhat-ethers-provider.ts:567:26)
      at HardhatEthersProvider.getBalance (node_modules\@nomicfoundation\hardhat-ethers\src\internal\hardhat-ethers-provider.ts:167:40)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test\Transaction.js:17:50)

I tried to use multiple ethereum addresses from
npx hardhat node 

and another addresses which exist in etherscan but I am still having the same error, how can solve this? should I deploy it to a testnet (e.g. sepolia testnet) before testing?
